# E-1100: Empty Model when using XPRESS (Mosel)

Tags: optimization, mosel

I'm building an optimisation model using FICO XPRESS for a project. The code runs fine up until the minimize(obj) line when I get error E-1100: Empty Problem. It seems to come down to the constraints not being recognised as constraints.

The documentation details the error as "We are trying to generate or load an empty problem into a solver (i.e. no constraints; bounds do not count as constraints)." (the last part is particularly unclear)

I have stripped the model back to the simplest formulation of constraints yet the same problem always occurs. I have a feeling it has to do with how the mpvar variables are being addressed or referred to. I have been using the record data structure which works great in all other regards although the same happens when I use arrays (and the same issue has afflicted a colleague who is using only arrays(we are working on an MSc assignment)

Any help would be greatly appreciated. I feel that this must be a common occurrence but there seems to be very little out there in the way of useful information.

Comment: Please edit the question to include relevant source code.

Comment: It's very likely that you forget to create decision variables using create(mpvar) command. But please share your source code.